# Sharepoint Task Items

Tags: workflow, permissions, wss-3.0, tasks

I am using a workflow which generates a task on the creation of new item of list.
I want that task visible to only 'Assigned To' people not the one who create it.
Tell me any way to do this. I have SPD.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need code to do it. Simply create a new view in the tasks list where the list is filtered by the Assigned To user being [Me] and set this to the default view.  Tasks will automatically be filtered by the current logged in user.

If you wanted to do it with code, you could create a dataview web part that filters the data by the current logged in user.

The DVWP route would be "more secure" in that the users wouldn't necessarily have dirtect access to the underlying list.  But to make it truly secure, you'd have to do item level permissions either in code or in the lists settings Advanced Settings.